# How to have the index reorder based on deletion

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am currently using Bootstrap Alert and Redux to create an alert system but I am running into an problem with displaying the alerts properly. I am currently displaying them as:

```
this.props.alerts.map((alert, index) => {
 return (<Alert>...<Alert/>)
}

and deleting with:
newArray = oldArray
newArray.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
```

So new alerts would be added to the Redux store and then be displayed on the page. The problem comes when there are multiple alerts and I start deleting starting at the first one. If there are two alerts on the page with indexes 0 and 1 and I delete the first alert, the second alert still has index 1. I assumed it would re-render since the `props` are no longer the same and re-index the alerts. So when I delete the second Alert, it still has the index of 1 but the array only has 1 alert in it so it fails to delete the alert. So when a new alert appears, it shows two instead of 1.

I have looked and saw about keys but I am unsure on the implementation with key into Redux

Comment: try `newArray = [...oldArray]`..

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I ended up implementing an index in my redux component to keep track of it